# Jakarta Faces 3: JSF-Tags are not translated into HTML-Tags

Tags: maven, tomcat, jsf

I have set up a  project in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate (Maven) for a university project with Java Enterprises and can also output the index.xhtml in the browser (via Tomcat 8.5.87). I am otherwise using Jakarta 9.1.0 and Jakarta Faces 3.0.0. As I am completely inexperienced with Tomcat, I wanted to ask for help with the following error that Tomcat is reporting:

```
**ERROR:**
03-Jan-2024 14:35:24.016 FEIN [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.loadClass Konnte Klasse [jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet] nicht laden
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420) [...]
```

**Below are my most important files for review:**

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mvc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                                  https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd">

</faces-config>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Login</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <p><img id="kopf_links" src="logo.jpg" width="150" alt="Logo"/></p>
    <p id="kopf_rechts">
        <h:outputText value="TEST!"/>
        <br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{anschrift.name}"/>
        <br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{anschrift.strasse} #{anschrift.hausnummer}"/>
        <br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{anschrift.plz} #{anschrift.ort}"/>
    </p>
</h:body>

</html>
```

I have already tried several times to test different dependencies (versions), restarted the server several times and followed all error messages of the IDE.

I would be grateful for any tips that could solve the problem!

Comment: @JasperdeVries I would ask you to give me more specific help, as I am very inexperienced in this area.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thanks for providing further information. I followed the instructions from "How to properly ..." and set up a GlassFish-Server 6.2.5 with JDK 18. But my problem didn't disappear: The JSF-Tags still aren't translated with both (!) servers. Any other ideas?

Comment: Tomcat doesn't provide JSF out the box because it isn't a Jakarta EE server. You need to install JSF manually via pom.xml. You only installed Jakarta MVC, Hibernate Core, GlassFish JAXB and Hibernate Validator. You didn't install JSF at all. You only mentioned that JSF API is provided by Tomcat while that isn't true at all. Carefully read abovelinked duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is your JSF file extension.

Your index file is named `index.xhtml` but your URL pattern in `servlet-mapping` is set to `*.jsf` file extension. Thus, it never calls your `FacesServlet`.

```
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
```

You need to map it to

```
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but unfortunately this change does not fix the error. I have read in another source that XHTML is transformed into JSF when the page is translated and therefore the mapping must be set to xhtml.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who tried to solve the problem. I have now helped myself by creating a new project in IntelliJ Ultimate and I have selected Jakarta EE Web (!) as the environment and the translation of the JSF tags worked without any problems. So it's clear that it wasn't my code, but the setup of the project in the IDE. Anyone who knows an explanation for this - I'm very curious!